# Turning my mobile into wifi hotspot using computer connection?

Tags: usb-connection-mode, wifi-hotspot

I know that my mobile can turn into a hotspot using a configuration option.
I know that my PC can use my mobile internet through the usb cable.

But is the other way possible ? Can my mobile use my PC internet connection and then broadcast it as a hotspot ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a PC with Wi-Fi, you don't need the mobile to create a hotspot: [How to Turn Your Windows PC Into a Wi-Fi Hotspot](http://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/)

You should also be able to use this method if you're getting the Internet connection on your PC through a mobile device via USB.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My pc isn't a laptop nor have a wifi card, so i can't use my computer to create an ad hoc. I knew about this way, that's why i'm looking for something using my mobile since it has wifi

Comment: Ah- well, that's why details are important. [Let me Google this for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+android+as+wireless+router&oq=use+android+as+wireless+router&aqs=chrome..69i57.8642j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=internet+connection+from+pc+to+android+via+usb)

Comment: I'm asking for a specific question, i don't understand how this detail is helpful